# Collecting hashes of all files in a folder and its subfolders into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, performance, file-system, hashcode

What I am doing here is iterating through all the files in the `parentFolder` and its subfolders collecting all the hashes of all the files and putting them into a dictionary where the key is the path of the file and the hash is the key:

```
def createDicts(parentFolder):
  hashesDict = {}
  for folderName, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk(parentFolder):        
    for fileName in fileNames:
      filePath = os.path.join(folderName, fileName)
      tempHash = getHash(filePath)
      hashesDict.update({filePath : tempHash})            
  return hashesDict
```

`getHash()` function:

```
def getHash (fileName):
  with open(fileName,"rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read() # Read file as bytes
    readableHash = hashlib.md5(bytes).hexdigest()
    return(readableHash)
```

Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: How long does it take now? Have you monitored system resources to see whether the process is IO-bound or CPU-bound?

Comment: Hi,
this is a new thing for me but i'll try to answer:
On a parentFolder that has 23992 files it took 8 seconds for the function to complete.
The CPU usage was 30% and number of threads were about 4220.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of code there's not much here in this snippet to go on to tell you how to make it faster as `getHash` isn't defined.

### Style

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is the standard style recommendation for Python. In it, it includes things like how many blank lines, how much indentation, recommendations for variable naming and casing.

There are linters ([Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), [Pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and others) which check your code against PEP-8 and issue useful warnings. In your case there are several simple and obvious things.

Standard indentation for Python is 4 spaces. Likewise variable names and function names should be `lower_snake_case`. You also have a tonne of whitespace and the end of your lines.

You may also want to look at [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) instead of `os.path` as the more modern way of handling paths.

### Temporaries

Instead of

```
hashesDict.update({filePath : tempHash})
```

you can use

```
hashesDict[filePath] = tempHash
```

which avoids creating the temporary.

You also aren't using `subFolders` so you can replace that with `_` to say this is irrelevant.

### Dict comprehension

To speed it up, you may find that a dict comprehension helps:

```
def create_dicts(parent_folder):
    return {os.path.join(folder_name, file_name): getHash(file_path)
            for folder_name, _, file_names in os.walk(parent_folder)
            for file_name in file_names}
```

but as I have no idea as to the expense of `getHash` that may be taking the time.

### `getHash`

Your `getHash` function loads the entire file into memory at once allocating and clearing large chunks of memory constantly, particularly if you have any large files this will be killer. The cleaner way of doing this is loading memory in chunks.

```
def getHash(filename: str, *, buffer_size: int = 65536) -> str:
    fhash = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as in_file:
        while chunk := in_file.read(buffer_size):
            fhash.update(chunk)
    return fhash.hexdigest()
```

**N.B** Choosing the right `buffer_size` can give some speedup, but will not be essential, `md5` isn't necessarily the best or fastest hash, alternatives are available.

Comment: Thank you i'll try this and sorry i forgot to include my getHash function, now my answer is updated properly.

Comment: @lungimiranza I have updated with more info on `getHash`